# Confidence interval for object counting

Tags: confidence-interval, object-detection

I'm working on object counting problem with deep learning object detection methods (specifically, yolo and faster rcnn). Is there any known method for uncertainty qunatification for object counting (i.e. predicted count $\pm$ x)?

Comment: It depends on the problem. Can you apply bootstrapping?

Comment: Are you looking for a [tag:prediction-interval], rather than a [tag:confidence-interval]? There is [a difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info).

Comment: That said, you can always fit models with various [quantile losses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/471224/1352) to predict conditional quantiles (which will give you prediction intervals, not confidence intervals, but it sounds like this is what you actually want).

Comment: Is it reasonable to apply bootstrapping? For example if I have 300 training images, then I would create, say, 30 bootstrapped samples each having 300 images drawn from the 300 training images with replacement. Then I train models on each samples, then run inference on the test data. Combining the results will give me a prediction bound?